# Unexpected end of file - ksh

Tags: shell, ksh

I am trying to execute a ksh script that calls a job in an Oracle product. When I run/execute my script, I get the following error:

```
$ sh test.sh  
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
test.sh: line 31: syntax error: unexpected end of file
$
```

Here is my code - Please tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
#
#  OEDQJobSubmit.sh

export BatchKey="AVG"

# Environment details: CURRENT

export OEDQUser=user1
export OEDQPass=password
export OEDQPORT=8090
export OEDQHOST=`hostname`

if [ ${BatchKey} = "AVG" ]; then
   export Job="Job-Averages"
   export Project="IPVFB-AVG"
fi

cd /ora/mw_etl/Oracle_EDQ1/oracle.edq/
/ora/java/sunjdk/bin/java -jar jmxtools.jar runjob -job "${Job}" -project "${Project}" -u ${OEDQUser} -p ${OEDQPass} ${OEDQHOST}:${OEDQPORT}

export ReturnCode=${?}

if [ ${ReturnCode} == 0 ]; then
   exit 0
else
   exit 1
fi
```

Thank You !

Comment: Why are you putting all your variables in the environment?  You can probably delete every occurrence of the word 'export' in your script, and you should understand the implications of doing so.

Comment: Also, the last 6 lines (assigning ReturnCode and then using it to specify the argument to exit) are totally redundant.  The script will exit with the return value of the last command that is executed.  (If you actually care about mapping all non-zero values to 1, just do `test $? = 0`, but you probably don't actually care about that.)

Comment: Well, the first if statement is not done, this script will be triggered for all jobs, i am trying to test it and see if it works for one at the moment. Also my BatchKey is hard coded currently. This will be removed, and when running this script, a argument will be passed through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a mistake, you are calling a `ksh` script with `sh` =)

2 solutions:

- `chmod +x test.sh; ./test.sh`

or

- `ksh test.sh`

Comment: if I use ksh test.sh i get the following:

$ ksh test.sh 
: not found [No such file or directory]
: not found [No such file or directory]
: not found [No such file or directory]
: not found [No such file or directory]
test.sh: line 14: syntax error at line 31: `if' unmatched

Comment: if i use chmod +x test.sh; ./test.sh ..... I get the following: 

$ chmod +x test.sh; ./test.sh
-ksh: ./test.sh: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: So it looks like copy and past does not work. I basically rewrote my whole program in vi editor on the linux server and ran it using ksh test.sh. It works. Thanks guys.

What i did before was wrote the program in Notepad++ and copy /past to linux. Just be aware, do not do that

Answer (score 1):

Your file contains carriage returns.

Run your script through `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\r'`.